# Using length() for a new class in R

Tags: class, r

I am trying to use the function `length()` on the class `item` to reveive the length of the vector `options`.

```
setClass(Class = "item",
  representation = representation(
    options = "character"
  ),
  prototype = prototype(
    options = character()
  )
)
setGeneric("length")
setMethod("length", signature(x = "item"), definition = function(x) length(x@options))
```

However, I always get the following error:

```
Error: could not find function "getGeneric"
Warning:
In .rk.get.structure.global(".__C__item") :
  failure to get object .__C__item
```

I am using `R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30)` with RKWard Version 0.5.7z+0.5.8+devel1.

Comment: It's strange, it works fine for me (R 2.13.1)

Comment: OK, there seems to be a problem with RKWard Version 0.5.7z+0.5.8+devel1. The code runs without difficulty in the plain R shell.

Comment: `methods::setGeneric` / `methods::setMethod`, because RKWard has been too clever?

Comment: Then I suggest you to switch to RStudio or the great combo Eclipse/StatET :-)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `methods` package doesn't load at startup.  Call

```
library(methods)
```

Comment: hm, that didn't make a difference

Comment: @woobert It's wired. I have the same situation, but this works for me.